# WKWebView not redirecting from PHP location code

Tags: php, swift, xcode, redirect, wkwebview

I'm implementing the WKWebView to my app, and most have worked so far. But I have noticed a few things.

Just to clarify, I have added the App Transport Security Settings -> Allow Arbitrary Loads.

**Part 1 solved:**

Add this code to ur navigationdelegate.

```
if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
    webView.load(navigationAction.request)
}
```

1) It appears the wkwebview won't redirect when you click to a new link that has a PHP location redirect. (But it works when you add it as start URL of the browser in code)

When I try to click on a link that has the PHP Location() code in it, I capture the URL and put it in the text field, and I can see that it just stops on the page.

2) I have some code that captures the current URL, but this also gets the URLs of resources loaded from the page - thereby making that the last URL.

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
var webView: WKWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldURL: UITextField!

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()

    webView = WKWebView(frame: (containerView?.bounds)!, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    webView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.11, green:0.13, blue:0.19, alpha:1)
    webView.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.11, green:0.13, blue:0.19, alpha:1)
    webView.isOpaque = false
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    self.containerView?.addSubview(webView!)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myURL = URL(string: "link removed")
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    webView.load(myRequest)

}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    print(navigationAction.request.url!)
    textFieldURL.text = navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}

@IBAction func buttonURL(_ sender: Any) {
    textFieldURL.text = webView.url?.absoluteString
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

PHP page with redirect:

```
<?php

if(!isset($_GET['id'])){
    exit();
}
$redirect = "some url";
header('Location: '.html_entity_decode($redirect));
exit();

?>
```

Comment: The "Part 1 solved" section helped me a lot, thanks for sharing! You could just post it as an answer to your own question. I almost missed it because I thought there were no answers.